# How do you atomically add an item to a virtual list that has a fixed number of elements?

Tags: list, concurrency, redis

We have lists with fixed sizes that will get populated concurrently by different processes.  Is there a way to perform this without using TRANSACTIONS?

For example, is there an atomic operation where you add an item to a list ONLY if the size of the list is smaller than X?

Answer (score 1):

There is no single command, which will add an item to a list only if the list contains less than n items. You would need to wrap them into a transaction in order to make them "atomic".
The only way to implement an atomic call without transactions would be via a LUA script. Something along the lines (pseudo code):

```
local len = redis.call("LLEN", KEYS[1])
if len >= ARGV[1] then
    return nil
end
redis.call("LPUSH", KEYS[1], ARGV[2])
return ARGV[2]
```

You would call this LUA script with the key-name of the list (KEYS[1]), the maximum length of the list (ARGV[1]) and the item that's supposed to be put on the list (ARGV[2]). Only if the length of the list is less than the maximum will the item be added and returned. If the list length is greater-equal to the maximum "nil" will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

I'll begin my answer with a question: why are you so reluctant to use transactions to ensure atomicity? Note that Redis' design is such that it provides you with flexible building blocks that you can put together to implement all kinds of patterns. If an atomic command doesn't exist, you're encouraged to use [MULTI/EXEC](http://redis.io/commands/multi) blocks or [Lua](http://redis.io/commands/eval) scripts to achieve the same effect using existing primitives.

So the answer's no, Redis doesn't have an atomic command that can add an item and keep a fixed-sized list. This pattern is popularly implemented with a [LTRIM](http://redis.io/commands/ltrim) or [LRANGE](http://redis.io/commands/lrange), depending on the exact type of behavior you're looking for (e.g. what happens what trying to add an item to a "full" list, is an empty/smaller list possible and how are items always pushed before popping). While in some cases transactionality can be eschewed, most times you'll want to ensure that there are no race conditions in the list's management.